# .Net ReportViewer report header text causes extra columns when report is exported to Excel

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have an ASP.Net application which uses ReportViewer to generate RDLC reports. I have noticed that when exporting the report(s) to Excel the exporter inserts extra columns where the header text of the report appears (text in the header of the report, not the column headings). If I remove the header text, no columns are added.

As these extra columns cause some confusion to the users, is there a way to tell the exporter not to export the header text when exporting into Excel?

c.